# To get OpenCV VideoWriter work across platforms consistently for MP4 container with H264 encoding

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, mp4, x264, fourcc

I am trying to get OpenCV VideoWriter work across platform consistently for MP4 container with H246 encoding.

Target platforms in order of importance - Ubuntu, Raspbian, OSX

Basically, my shortcoming at this point is not understanding the relationship of FourCC code (as a parameter to OpenCV VideoWriter) to the FFMPEG backend and its requirements. I am interested to understand the game in play rather than discussing a piece of code.

What I want to know is when I specify 'X264' as FourCC code trying to write an x.MP4 file (FFMPEG backend) and the request is marshalled to FFMPEG what requirements/dependencies need to be satisfied by the OS for it to success.

So far I have got my python stack writing MP4 video files across Raspbian/Ubuntu/OSX, with a hack.

On my Raspbian stretch installation, I use 0x00000021 as the fourCC code.
On Ubuntu (VM on OSX) and on OSX, AVC1 works.

Days of Googling only delivered those hacks, not a good understanding of the problem.

The x264 as FourCC code leads to one of - failure, non-portable video file + annoying FFMPEG warning.

I am trying to get to the bottom of it.

The code,

```
    #self.__fourCC = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('x', '2', '6', '4')
    self.__fourCC = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('a', 'v', 'c', '1')
    if PlatformUtils.isRunningOnRaspberryPi():
        self.__fourCC = 0x00000021
```

I have control over the version both OpenCV and FFMPEG (if required GStreamer too). I can and have built them for Ubuntu/Raspbian.

Comment: What's the error message if you try to use `avc1` on Raspbian?

Comment: @aergistal

When I use avc1 with mp4 extension, I get the foillowing:

```OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x31637661/'avc1' is not supported with codec id 28 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000021/'!???'```

But it does create the file and it plays on RPI (VLC) and OSX

Hence I used the magic number to get rid of the warning.


But, when I use avc1 with avi extension, OpenCV does not complain but the file it generates plays on RPI but on OSX I get back frames for time duration.

Comment: first, from opencv site, fourcc codes are platfrom dependent
FourCC is a 4-byte code used to specify the video codec. The list of available codes can be found in fourcc.org.

Comment: FFMPEG needs to be built with `libx264` in order for it to have `H.264` encoding/decoding capability. In all your different platforms, in terminal run: `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i avc`. The output string must start with `DEV.LS`.